# FlinkKafkaConsumer read from the start of the topic

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to read a kafka topic as a datastream in Flink. I am using `FlinkKafkaConsumer` to read the topic.

The problem that I am facing is that after a few testing with I want to start reading again from the start of the topic to do some extra bit of testing. Ideally changing the `group.id` and restarting the job both should be enough to accomplish this.

But after restart, the consumer is still able to find the old checkpoints/kafka.commit. I also tried to delete all the checkpoints delete all configMaps and deployments and restart everything but the same thing happened again. I can see the offsets being set in taskmanager logs.

How to read from the start of the topic again?

```
2021-02-17 10:08:41,287 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain-2, groupId=FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain] Discovered group coordinator idsp-cdp-qa-ehns-2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2021-02-17 10:08:41,324 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain-2, groupId=FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain] Setting offset for partition adhoc-testing-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=40204, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=idsp-cdp-qa-ehns-2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=-1}}
2021-02-17 10:08:41,326 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain-2, groupId=FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain] Setting offset for partition adhoc-testing-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=39962, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=idsp-cdp-qa-ehns-2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=-1}}
2021-02-17 10:08:41,328 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain-2, groupId=FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain] Setting offset for partition adhoc-testing-4 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=40444, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=idsp-cdp-qa-ehns-2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=-1}}
2021-02-17 10:08:41,328 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain-2, groupId=FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain] Setting offset for partition adhoc-testing-2 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=40423, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=idsp-cdp-qa-ehns-2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=-1}}
2021-02-17 10:08:41,328 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator [] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain-2, groupId=FlinkChangeConsumerNewAgain] Setting offset for partition adhoc-testing-3 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=40368, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=idsp-cdp-qa-ehns-2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=-1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the problem is that consumer is able to find old commits or old checkpoints as long as You are starting the job from scratch not from savepoint.

The issue seems to be that You don't set the `auto.offset.reset` on Kafka Consumer, which means that default value is used, which is `latest`. So, whenever You start a job with new `group.id` it will always start from the latest offsets committed to Kafka. You can change that by simply passing `auto.offset.reset` property set to `earliest` on properties passed to KafkaConsumer.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, provided the job isn't recovering from a checkpoint, or being started from a savepoint:

```java
FlinkKafkaConsumer<T> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(...);
myConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();
```

Otherwise the default is to start from the committed group offsets.

Sounds like you've already seen this explanation [in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-start-position-configuration), but just in case:

> Note that these start position configuration methods do not affect the start position when the job is automatically restored from a failure or manually restored using a savepoint. On restore, the start position of each Kafka partition is determined by the offsets stored in the savepoint or checkpoint (please see the next section for information about checkpointing to enable fault tolerance for the consumer).

Comment: Thanks @David for the swift reply. But here is my concern does it mean if I try to read the same kafka topic from a different job that would lead to they sharing the queue instead of both getting copies of the same messages? Even though the group.ids are different?

Comment: Just tried running the same code with a different job name and it is also using the same offset. (without the ```setStartFromEarliest```).
My understanding is that different group.id should lead to different offsets.

Comment: I would expect a new consumer group would read from the start, without having to explicitly call `setStartFromEarliest`. How are you setting the consumer group id?

Comment: Setting with the properties file. I checked that everytime the groupID is different as checked from the logs that I pasted in the question

Comment: What do You mean by the same offset?